# Cygwin: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: cygwin

If anyone could help I'd be grateful. Downloaded cygwin today to run HMMer on Windows. All was fine but when I was following installation instructions until came across this error when running 'configure' program listed in directory of software. Couldn't find an answer online so thought I would try here. Below is a copy of command line:

> C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Fasciola Sequence\Programs for BLAST
>   Searches>cd hmmer-3 .1b2-cygwin64
>
> C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Fasciola Sequence\Programs for BLAST
>   Searches\hmmer-3.1b 2-cygwin64>ls COPYRIGHT    Userguide.pdf 
>   configure      install-sh     share INSTALL      aclocal.m4
>   configure.ac   lib            src LICENSE      binaries
>   documentation  libdivsufsort  testsuite Makefile.in  config.guess
>   easel          profmark       tutorial README       config.sub
>   include        release-notes
>
> C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Fasciola Sequence\Programs for BLAST
>   Searches\hmmer-3.1b 2-cygwin64>./configure '.' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Thanks to anyone who can help!
P

Comment: Are you trying to run that in a normal Windows command prompt?

Comment: Yes, is is possible to do so? The other unix commands appeared to be working so I just assumed it would work as well.

Comment: `./` is a Linux construct, if you want to use it, you use a Linux shell.

Comment: Thanks for you help!